# Performance Tuning for an insert query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance

Can someone help me in tuning this query as I am new to performance tuning in oracle.

```
INSERT INTO mdm_id_relation
    SELECT 
        pat_key, hub_pat_id, msa_pat_id, pat_id
    FROM 
        ods_raw_patient_mdm_process p1
    WHERE NVL (pat_id, 'NULL') IN (SELECT pat_id
                                   FROM mdm_id_relation)
      AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT pat_key
                      FROM mdm_id_relation p2
                      WHERE p1.pat_key = p2.pat_key);
```

Comment: Add the explain plan, and table structure for three source tables.

Comment: You could start by replacing NVL(pat_id, 'NULL') with pat_id. Then the index on pat_id (if there is one) can be used.

Comment: Some idea of how many rows there are in each of the tables would be helpful. Are there any indexes? How long is it taking currently? What is the execution plan? [`xplanx.sql`](http://www.williamrobertson.net/documents/xplanx.html)

Comment: Can you explain the reason for `NVL(pat_id, 'NULL')`. are there any values with the string value `NULL` in table `mdm_id_relation`? `SELECT count(*) FROM mdm_id_relation WHERE pat_id = 'NULL'`

Answer (score 0):

To tune an INSERT query, you'll need the follwowing ingredients:

1. A place to test your query. Ideally a separate database, but a separate schema might do as well. Minimally a copy of the tables and indexes that are involved. *Reason:* the INSERT will change data, you'll need to run different versions of the query until you are happy with the performance.
2. The test tables need to have exactly the same structure as the real table and roughly the same amount of data as the real thing. *Reason:* The performance of the INSERT depends heavily on both structure and amount.
3. Up to date statistics: Look up `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS` and how to use it. *Reason:* Give the query optimizer a chance to find a good query plan.
4. A way to measure performance (wall clock seconds or Oracle costs etc.), and, even better, access to the query plan (SQL Developer: Explain Plan button, or have a look at William's script).

When I need to tune `INSERT` statements, I normally start with the `SELECT` part until I am happy with it. Firstly run `SELECT ...`, when that is fine, I run a `CREATE TABLE foo NOLOGGING AS SELECT ...` to measure the SELECT of all the rows. When thats fine, I test the whole `INSERT ... SELECT ...` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Any issue with performance is going to be the `select`, not the `insert`.  I think this is an equivalent query:

```
INSERT INTO mdm_id_relation (pat_key, hub_pat_id, msa_pat_id, pat_id) -- always list the columns!
    SELECT pat_key, hub_pat_id, msa_pat_id, pat_id
    FROM ods_raw_patient_mdm_process p1
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mdm_id_relation mir
                  WHERE mir.pat_id = p1.pat_id
                 ) AND
          NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM mdm_id_relation mir
                      WHERE p1.pat_key = mir.pat_key
                     );
```

For this query, you want two indexes:  `mdm_id_relation(pat_id)` and `mdm_id_relation(pat_key)`.  These should be a big help on performance.

Note:  Test the `select` first before doing the insert.